# Custom default navigation level in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone

When you tap a tab on a UITabBar that is already selected, and that view controller is a navigation controller, the navigation controller pop's to the root view controller. How would I change this behavior to pop to a different level than the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your UITabBarController delegate and do the following:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return tabBarController.selectedViewController != viewController;
}
```

The above code will prevent popping to the root. To manually pop to a different level you have to write code to do the following in `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`:

1. Check if `viewController` is the particular navigation controller you're interested in
2. Check what the top view controller of the navigation controller is and determine which vc you want to pop to
3. Use `[navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES]` or one of the other navigation controller push/pop methods to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can play arround this by using the UITabBarControllerDelegate:

try returning NO when the view controller is the root controller and push or pop the controller you need. May be you will need to work with some flag when you really need to pop to the root controller.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```